# How do change this procedure to delete the records day by day in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hey all, I am just getting lazy now. But, I know you all can help me and that's a great thing.

I have a table cleanup and delete proceedure that runs every night. It's basic enough and it is suppossed to delete any records in the database that are older than 3 days.

The proceedure is failing each night because when we delete more than 1 days worth of records at a time, I get a transaction log full error. It would be a pain to change the transaction log settings.

SOO, can somebody show me how to update the proc so that it deletes everything back from 3 days ago, lets say through 7 days. Meaning go back 3 days, then delete each table's data one at a time for the past 7 days.

We're a 24x7 monitored energy shop, and I can be sure if it doesn't run for 7 days someone will notice.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[PruneData]
    (
    @cutoffDate DateTime
    )
AS
BEGIN
    declare @threeDayCutoffDate DATETIME
    set @threeDayCutoffDate  = dateadd(hh, 5, DATEADD(dd, -3,dbo.DateOnly(getutcdate())))
    delete from LMP_DayAhead where interval < @threeDayCutoffDate
    delete from LMP_RealTime where interval < @threeDayCutoffDate
    delete from LMP_RealTimeIntegrated where interval < @threeDayCutoffDate
    delete from ZonalMCP where interval < @threeDayCutoffDate
    delete from SyncJob where synctime < @threeDayCutoffDate
    RETURN
END
```

Comment: Hey, You work at a Power company! cool.

Comment: Look into partitioning... that's the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To reduce the log pressure you need to delete in batches. Something like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[PruneData]
    (
    @cutoffDate DateTime
    )
AS
BEGIN
    declare @threeDayCutoffDate DATETIME
    declare @rows bigint;
    declare @batchsize int;
    set @threeDayCutoffDate  = dateadd(hh, 5, DATEADD(dd, -3,dbo.DateOnly(getutcdate())))
    set @batchsize = 1000;
    while (1=1)
    begin
        set @rows = 0;
        delete top (@batchsize) from LMP_DayAhead where interval < @threeDayCutoffDate;
        set @rows = @rows + @@ROWCOUNT;
        delete top (@batchsize) from LMP_RealTime where interval < @threeDayCutoffDate
        set @rows = @rows + @@ROWCOUNT;
        delete top (@batchsize) from LMP_RealTimeIntegrated where interval < @threeDayCutoffDate
        set @rows = @rows + @@ROWCOUNT;
        delete top (@batchsize) from ZonalMCP where interval < @threeDayCutoffDate
        set @rows = @rows + @@ROWCOUNT;
        delete top (@batchsize) from SyncJob where synctime < @threeDayCutoffDate
        set @rows = @rows + @@ROWCOUNT;

        if 0 = @rows
        begin
            break;
        end
    end
    RETURN
END
```

There are many ways to optimize this, eg. once a table is pruned skip it on next loop iteration. The ultimate optimization is to avoid the delete completely. Instead use a rolling window partition switch scheme: partition your tables by day and have every day switch out the last partition and switch in a new one. This is almost instantaneous.  See [Transferring Data Efficiently by Using Partition Switching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191160.aspx), [Partitioned Tables and Indexes in SQL Server 2005](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345146%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) and [How to Implement an Automatic Sliding Window in a Partitioned Table on SQL Server 2005](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa964122%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)

Comment: Ahh perfect! that's the ticket!

Comment: @Paul, @Remus - I don't think simply breaking it into batches will get around the log becoming full.

Comment: @cyberwiki: if the transaction gets split across multiple batches then whatever exiting log reuse method (backup log, simple recovery model) is in place will get to do its job and recycle the log. With a single long transaction neither BACKUP nor simple recovery can do anything about the log growing.

Comment: @Remus - you miss the point. The log **cannot** be recycled until it has been backed up - so simply breaking it down as you have done won't solve it. You are still doing it in one go. The crux is that log must be backed up to be able to reuse space, otherwise there is no way to fully rebuild a database from backups and logs (if it were able to recycle away un-backed-up transactions).

Comment: I only upvote for the partition truncation solution. That's the ONLY way to go when your deletes are rather "untargeted".

Comment: @cyberwiki: a long running transaction will prevent log reuse despite all the log backups the overlap it. The purpose of batching is to break a long running transaction into smaller pieces. When this scheduled prune job will run, it will create many small transactions instead of few large ones (one per table). The regular scheduled log backup jobs will then have a chance to recycle the log, while the pruning is still running. The number of log bytes generated is similar, but the transaction break up allows for log space recycle from an overlapping log backup job. Hope this is clearer now.

Comment: @Stephanie: I would go into partitioning unless I'm really forced. The 'untargeted' deletes can be 'targeted' by choosing a proper clustered index (eg. `interval` in the OP tables). The overhead of partitioning can be quite big: Enterprise license, significant performance hit, and serious data modeling effects (eg. kiss all unique constraints good bye). So while it is blatantly fast to switch out old data, it is not necessarily the way to go.

Comment: Yeah I think Remus is correct, I updated the procedure and it worked where as it didn't work this morning after midnight and the old code. I am happy.

Comment: Besides, there are other benefits from batching updates/deletes: a top (1000) delete will likely not trigger X lock escalation to table level and thus will allow higher concurrency. And batching also reduces ordinary row lock contention, reduces the collision probability and will allow for a higher throughput, as delete batches will interleave with potential readers and both will make progress.

Comment: By untargeted I mean, en masse... entire days at a time. Unlike, every record with a flag = Y... second, he's going to have AT MOST 7 partitions (or 10 or 4) hard to tell precisely from the description of his requirement. When, precisely is partitioning a significant performance hit? Serious data modeling? He's deleting entire days worth of data, which makes me believe this table ain't the parent of anything, so while I'll agree that if he needs uniqueness enforced he may need an alternate strategy, it has little effect on the model.

Comment: As to the other benefits of... I admit that I never consider anything other than Ent Ed. Because I think almost solely at the level of enterprise solutions. That's my shortcoming. And I never consider that a database would have writers blocking readers. My main RDBMS is Oracle which doesn't have that issue. One major downside of delete over truncates is that a point-in-time recovery will have to playback ALL those deletes since the last full bu. Right? again, I'll defer if you correct me.

Comment: @Paul - if you happen to run this after a log backup, it may work by chance (that there is more free log space) even when it didn't this morning.

Comment: @Remus - so what you are saying is that (1) you expect this process to take hours? (2) transaction log backups (never mentioned in your answer) will kick in DURING the loops, allowing log space reuse?  Have I got your message right?  Personally, I would be worried if any such prune action (for 1 day of any day) takes over minutes to run.

Comment: @cyberwiki: yes. I've seen such pruning nightly job running for hours on regular basis. After all every record added must be deleted, so is not unreasonable to expect that what took 24 hours to insert takes in a little more than just minutes to delete. Normally log backup tasks run at 10-15 minutes intervals, so they overlap such pruning maintenance for 2-3 times or even more.

Comment: Well from my experience it usually takes less than 45 seconds to complete. The LMP_Realtime table is the biggest with about 700k records a day.  Looks like cyberwiki might be right, it failed this morning! :)  I wish I could try the partitioning stuff, but we aren't that advanced around here and trying new things scares people!

Comment: if is only 700k stuff then perhaps the issue is that your log is too small. Just grow your log file to a size where it can accommodate the delete. Also time the prune job to start soon after a log backup job just finished so the log is free and re-usable.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you broke it into batches, from start to end you will need to delete the same amount of records within the same timeframe (of seconds/minutes). The transaction log needs to keep all of these recorded until you have either done a full or log backup.

What you need to do is instead increase the transaction log backup frequency, and put log backups **between** the batches of your deletion runs.  So let's say you expect roughly 1 million records to be deleted per day.  Even though you have said to go back and delete 7 days (offset by 3), let's design the system to cope with 3 days at a time.  So if you had not run it for 7 days (shouldn't happen since you state this runs **every day**), it will take 3 days to catch up (doing 3 a day).

Next step is to break it into batches.

```
delete top(10000) from LMP_DayAhead where interval < @threeDayCutoffDate
delete top(30000) from LMP_RealTime where interval < @threeDayCutoffDate
delete top(20000) from LMP_RealTimeIntegrated where interval < @threeDayCutoffDate
delete top(50000) from ZonalMCP where interval < @threeDayCutoffDate
delete top(1000) from SyncJob where synctime < @threeDayCutoffDate
```

Where each TOP(X) is designed to cover about 1 day's worth.

Finaly, schedule extra transaction log backups at 1:00am and 1:20am, and for this job to run at 12:50am, 1:10am, 1:30am, each batch taking 1 day's worth of data off.  The transaction log backups in between will keep the log clean for the next run.

This is the general strategy but you can tweak it to suit your needs.